# While install dlib, process got stuck and does nothing

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pip, dlib

I'm using amazon EC2, ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I tried to install 'dlib' on my instance, but as the below image, process got stucked and do nothing. If I press ctrl+c, installation being cancelled. How can I install dlib on my instance?

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqNH7.png)

```
python3 -m pip install dlib
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... |
```

I already install CMake and I tried python3 -m pip install dlib. I want to install dlib successfully.

Comment: Why do you think it does nothing? `dlib` distributed in source-only form so `pip` has to compile it. Most probably it's compilation going on behind the scene. If EC2 instance doesn't have a lot of memory and processor power the compilation could go on for quite long.

Comment: @phd First of all, thanks for your reply :) But I waited an hour and a half. Also progress bar was not moving ((pyproject.toml) ... | <-this bar) , so I thought it was doing nothing or stucked at somewhere.

Comment: As you said my ec2 instance type is for free tier, so I can reboot my instance and try once more. This time I'm going to spend more time. And then I will make more reply.

Comment: Also monitor what processes are running during `pip install`. Most of the time should be `gcc` compiler.

Comment: BTW why not install precompiled `dlib` with `conda`? https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dlib

Comment: @phd Hi! I just resolved my problem, with a simple solution. Problem was my ec2 instance memory. My ec2 instance memory was 1GB, and spring boot server was running at the same time. So I made a swap memory, and I use "pip install dlib", and after 30 minutes installation was completed. Your first comment was right. Thx for ur comment :)